# Cannot use macros in c++ class declaration

Tags: c++, class

I am using GNU C++ 4.4.7 on linux machine to compile the following code:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifdef _LOG_SHLIB_EXPORT
#define LOG_SHLIB _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LOG_SHLIB _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class LOG_SHLIB debug_logger    <--- "Syntax error"
{

...
};
```

Comment: When positing questions regarding build-errors, please include the *complete* and *unedited* error output in the body of the question.

Comment: Also, according to [this article](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) it says "... that non-Windows builds of GCC don't offer an equivalent to __declspec(dllexport)..."

Comment: What build of GCC are you using? Is it windows build? As said neither `_declspec` nor `__declspec` has any particular meaning on other builds.

Comment: The complete error: Description Resource Path Location Type
expected initializer before ‘debug_logger’.                .


I'm using an ubuntu build. It's a code that works on Windows with Visual C++ 10 and I'm trying to port it on linux.

Comment: Thank you skyking for clarifying this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's __declspec(dllexport) with a double underscore. Not _declspec(dllexport) with only one.
Secondly, There is NO such thing as __declspec(dllexport) in Linux. We simply don't care if it's a function in a so file(dll on Unix systems) or if I want to import/export it.

This should be what you want.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    #ifdef _LOG_SHLIB_EXPORT  
        #define LOG_SHLIB __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define LOG_SHLIB __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define LOG_SHLIB
#endif

class LOG_SHLIB debug_logger
{
    ........
};
```

Comment: You have forgotten to make underscores in your code double, they are still single now, despite your explanation.

Comment: oops, tkx, it's now fixed

Comment: I have used the suggested code and I got rid of the error. Thank you Mary